Get Firebase AppCheck Token on .NET backend
I'm trying to upload an image to the Firebase Storage from the .NET backend. Everything is working till I activate AppCheck for Storage. And I started to get the error "Firebase App Check token is invalid."
How to configure the backend to pass AppCheck on the Firebase successfully?
